# A Voting Based Feature/Product Request System that is not a Bug Tracker

Tags: user-feedback

A year or so ago I came across a feature request system where customers could request a product or feature request and vote it.

The system was nice as every customer got three votes that they could assign/unassign to whatever request they liked best.

But this was not a bug tracker.  It had a much cleaner and simpler interface than most bug tracking packages out there.

I can't for the life of me remember what site I saw it on or what package it is, does any one know of any package that offers such functionality?

Comment: https://alternativeto.net/software/uservoice/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://www.dreamhost.com have a system like this for feature suggestions - I currently have 55 credits which I can use to vote suggestions up or down; more credits are required for harder problems. Theirs looks to be in-house, but there are a few similar ones listed here: http://mashable.com/2011/03/06/user-feedback-apps/

Of which, I like the look of UserVoice, CrowdSound, and SuggestionBox.

Comment: super thanks, so many options :-)

Answer (score 2):

The site you are looking for is called uservoice.com . I am pretty sure you are referring to the same site. It has support help desk but also has suggestions. These suggestions will popup on left as soon the customer starts typing. If he sees his suggestion already there, he can simply vote to it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying something like [reddit's source](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki) where users can create 'subreddits' representing projects. Within a project, users can then post their requests which can be voted on by the community. Could be fun to try :)